# Term/use for "comparable-only" upper bounds?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

I just noticed there is a definition that is "missing" from order theory. Let $(X,\leqslant)$ be any type of (pre-) ordered set and $S\subseteq X$. Define the predicates ($I$ for "inclusion," $C$ for "comparability")

\begin{align}
I_\text{weak}&=x\in X & C_\text{weak}&=\forall s\in S:x\leqslant s\implies s\leqslant x  \\\\
I_\text{strong}&=x\in S & C_\text{strong}&=\forall s\in S:s\leqslant x. 
\end{align}

Then we have

\begin{align}
I_\text{weak}\wedge C_\text{weak}&\Longleftrightarrow\;? \\\\
I_\text{weak}\wedge C_\text{strong}&\Longleftrightarrow x\text{ is an upper bound of }S\\\\
I_\text{strong}\wedge C_\text{weak}&\Longleftrightarrow x\text{ is maximal in }S\\\\
I_\text{strong}\wedge C_\text{strong}&\Longleftrightarrow x\text{ is a maximum/greatest element of }S.
\end{align}

**Is there a term for the first condition, and is it ever relevant or useful?**

Comment: A twisted way to say this is "$x$ is maximal in $\{x\}\cup S$".